# Call the session in codeigniter framework which is already declared in parent php folder outside the codeigniter folder

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

My main project is created in core php and I am working on one module which is in codeigniter in same project folder.

```
$_SESSION['UserName'] = $loginDetailAr['UserName'];
$_SESSION['UserType'] = $loginDetailAr['UserType'];
$_SESSION['UserTypeName'] = $loginDetailAr['UserTypeName'];
$_SESSION['IsAdmin'] = $loginDetailAr['IsAdmin'];
```

Comment: No session can be called outside the application. If can thinks about the Project Security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can help you

```
   $this->load->library('session');
```

$result = $this->login_model->userLogin($email, $password);

```
if ($result) {
    $sess_array = array();
    foreach ($result as $loginDetailAr) {
        $sess_array = array(
            'UserName' => $loginDetailAr->UserName,
            'UserType' => $loginDetailAr->UserType,
            'UserTypeName' => $loginDetailAr->UserTypeName,
            'IsAdmin' => $loginDetailAr->IsAdmin,
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    return TRUE;
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', ' Invalid Email Or Password ');
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the session library

```
$this->load->library('session');
// can access variables with this->session
$is_admin = $this->session->IsAdmin;
```

For more details please refer.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html